# Domain validation with hooks

Tags: hook, whmcs

I have problem with domain validation of Cyrillic domains (.мкд), but only when SLD contains only numbers. I get error "Domain is not valid". WHMCS's domain validation file is encrypted. How to make hook to validate domain and "roundabout" encrypted WHMCS template file for domain validation?